# how to query on website and get the result data in excel automatically

Tags: powerquery

here is a website
https://olbs.amsschennai.gov.in/nsweb/FlightBriefing/#showMetars

one can click on observation tab and search  with airport code like
VABB VIDO VIJP seperated with space. and click te onw of the button to query the result.

I have the codes in excel in column A. ONE Code in each row and wish to get the result in next column using some power query

i didnt try anyting,i am not a prorammer.
i am expectin to get the result in excel if some methods can work.